# Nested little $o$ notation

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to "nest" little $o$ notations?

For example, in showing the chain rule for a function $f(u(x))$ (the example is taken from [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/DerivativeProofs.aspx), if we define $k = h\times[ u'(x) + o(h) ]$, for $h\in\mathbb{R}$ can we describe
$$
o(k) = o(h \times [o(h) + u'(x)]) = o(h\times u'(x))
$$
or does this not make sense?

It seems that in this case, since $o(h)$ is dominated by $h$, it'd be fine here, but not sure about this or about nesting generally.

Comment: It depends which one is larger, $o(h)$ or $u'(x)$. If $o(h)$ is larger than $u'(x)$ then it would simplify to $o(h^2)$.

Comment: @GregMartin's point notwithstanding, $o(h^2)\subseteq o(h)$.

Comment: I imagine that if $u'(x)$ is larger than $o(h)$, then it's safe to write $o(h u'(x))$. So it seems we could always safely write this?

Comment: @J.G. that requires some assumption on $h$ that won't be true in general. Also, $o(hu'(x))$ itself might or might not be $o(h)$.

Comment: @GregMartin $o(h^2)\subseteq o(h)$ is a statement about sets of functions of a bound variable $h$, not claims contingent on the value of some free $h$. The only "assumption" is we're looking at $\to0$ limits. Your other concern submits to the same point,  at any fixed $x$ where derivatives are defined or evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

This idea is workable; let's spell out how it works. I'll use different notation so we don't have to remember which variable's small variation is $h$, which is $k$ etc. We have$$\delta u\in u^\prime(x)\delta x+o(\delta x),\,\delta f\in f^\prime(u)\delta x+o(\delta u),$$where each ${}^\prime$ has an obvious-in-context meaning. So$$\delta u\in f^\prime(u)(u^\prime(x)\delta x+o(\delta x))+o(u^\prime(x)\delta x+o(\delta x)).$$Even easier to read is$$\delta u\in(u^\prime+o(1))\delta x,\,\delta f\in(f^\prime+o(1))\delta u=(f^\prime+o(1))(u^\prime+o(1))\delta x.$$The $\delta x$ coefficient is $f^\prime u^\prime+\underbrace{o(f^\prime)+o(u^\prime)+o(1)}_{o(1)}$.

Comment: in the last line, what does this say? That as $\delta x\to0$, $\delta f$ is $o(f'u')$?

Comment: @jjjjjj No, that $\delta f\in(f^\prime u^\prime+o(1))\delta x$.